# Google App Engine Xmpp chat how to manage the status of the users?

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp, channel-api

It is easy to play with xmpp and the channel api to obtain a chat like...

http://www.dev-articles.com/article/Google-App-Engine-sending-messages-with-XMPP-393002

is an example, although I'm fighting a bit to understand the best way to manage the status of the users. Anyone with some experience about it?

I read the part "User Presence" in the documentation http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview.html I still don't have a grasp of it...

Comment: I don't understand what you want to know.  You should probably update your question to be more specific.

Comment: I want to understand what I need to do to manage the presence of the users with xmpp within app engine in particular what is the logic behind the handlers : /_ah/xmpp/presence/available/ ,
/_ah/xmpp/presence/unavailable/, /_ah/xmpp/presence/probe/

Comment: What do you need to know that the relevant section of the docs (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview.html#Handling_User_Presence) doesn't explain?

Comment: I think I have a good grasp now, well wasn't clear to me. In the documentation wasn't clear to me that if you want to manage the status you have to store the information and when you receive a request to presence you have to replay accordingly. If I have time I post the example here as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think I know a bit more now, so this is how I manage the status of a xmpp account with google app appengine.

[Xmpp status in app engine](http://www.dev-articles.com/article/Google-app-engine-xmpp-managing-the-status-404001)

Comment: It was nice of you to write a blog entry, but it would be nice if you could summarize your findings in this answer.

Comment: sure, it is not difficult after all. You have to handle the status somewhere for the users. Add a listener for the probe call, and reply accordingly to the status of the user.